# Query documents in an array in mongodb using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to query all documents present inside an Array which itself is present in a MongoDB collection under Node.js.

For example: I have a DB with a structure:

```
{
  "name1":[{"height":"5.5"},
           {"weight":"57"}],
  "name2":[{"height":"6.1"},
           {"weight":"74"}]
}
```

What query should I make to get all the documents( i.e. height, weight) of the array "name1"

Output should be :

```
{ 
  { "height":"5.5"}
  {"weight":"57"}
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to reorganise the collection so each document has a key of name and key of physicalattributes e.g.

```
{
   'name' : 'name1', 
    'physAttr': ['height': heightvalue,
                      'weight': weightvalue]
}
```

then suppose you wanted to find all documents with height 5.5, the query would be trivial

```
db.collection.find({ 'physAttr.height': 5.5 })
```

As described in the question each document in the collection has a different schema from the others (different name key for every document) making query operations difficult.